# How to get EMI Calculator module

Tags: 7

I am developing a Real Estate website for that i need EMI calculator Module.
From where i can get this.

Is there any module is developed for EMI Calculator

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search gives me the impression  that there is no such module available just yet.

Feel free to provide it to the community if you want ;-)

You can take a look here if you want:

http://emicalculator.net/emi-calculator-widget

That might  give you a good starting point.